# Allow X-API-Key in either header or query for OpenAPI/Swagger

Tags: python, authorization, openapi, connexion

I am using `ApiKeyAuth` in OpenAPI (with Python and Connexion) and want to be able to pass the `X-API-Key` parameter either in the `header` or the `query`. The spec seems to suggest I can only have one or the other, not both at the same time.

This way simply overwrites the key so only the `header` method is available:

```
openapi: '3.0.0'
...
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: query
      name: X-API-Key
      x-apikeyInfoFunc: app.apikey_auth
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: header
      name: X-API-Key
      x-apikeyInfoFunc: app.apikey_auth
...
```

This causes an `oneOf` validation error:

```
components:
  securitySchemes:
    ApiKeyAuth:
      type: apiKey
      in: 
        - header
        - query
      name: X-API-Key
      x-apikeyInfoFunc: app.apikey_auth
```

The result I want is to be able to do:

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/acme" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "X-API-Key: test12345"
```

Or:

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:8000/acme?X-API-Key=test12345" -H  "accept: application/json"
```

Comment: The 1st example is correct, you just need to rename the 2nd `ApiKeyAuth` to something else. See the ^^ linked question for the complete example.

Comment: Oh excellent, thank you that works. I didn't find it as I was searching for OpenAPI rather than Swagger.